# VB.NET Why my controls look older in VS19?

Tags: .net, vb.net, controls, visual-studio-2019, appearance

I recently updated my Visual Studio to 2019 and I'm surprised to see that when I start a new project and add controls, even though I can see them in the designer exactly the same way they were in the previous version, when I start the application all the controls look really old.
I thought the look of the controls depended on your Windows version, but when I execute a project that I compiled in the previous version of Visual Studio it does actually show controls the way I want.

So, to show you an example with the progress bar. This is what I used to see in the previous version of Visual Studio, and what I still see in projects that I built before updating the program:

[image: Image1]

And this is what I see in projects compiled with the new version of Visual Studio:

[image: Image2]

How can I come back to the previous look and style? I checked all the properties of the two projects to see if there was any difference and I found that .NET Framework 4.7.2 in the new version does not allow to enable Windows XP visual styles, while .NET Framework 4.5 in the old build does allow to modify these properties.

Thanks in advance for your help.
I'm running Windows 10 64bit by the way.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using .Net Core version of the template? Can you see the `Enable Application framework` option? Is your app starting from `Sub Main`? Have you added `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` in this case?

Comment: Read this one: [Winforms controls diaplay as V5 mode for Visual Basic project in runtime #1123](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/1123)

Comment: Did you choose a .Net Core template? Btw, what you saw there, related to the .Net Core template, is not exactly a *workaround*, it's more or less the standard in other languages. Also, Visual Studio 2019 is still pretty new, some other *details* are still a work in progress. You didn't specify what version of VS you're using, that's quite important. Did you install a Preview version?

Comment: The template was .Net Framework. It is the only option that appears for Windows Forms and Visual Basic. The version I'm using is 16.4.0

Comment: You then created your Project with the wrong template or you didn't install all the Visual Studio Desktop support packages. Check out the Visual Studio installer.

Answer (score 4):

I had a problem with migrated project from older Visual Studio. Buttons and TextBoxes were looking outdated in running application (however not in the Designer).

The solution is to add `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` in Main.
In C# code looks like this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main() 
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new frmMain());
}
```

With VB I am not very familiar, but I believe it is so:

```
<System.STAThread()> Public Shared Sub Main()
  Application.EnableVisualStyles()
  Application.Run(New Form1)
End Sub
```

Hope this helps to anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after few hours of searching the Internet. I did not want to do any workaround, as instructed in most of the articles. This is a new project, fresh install of VS2019, and this should work without shenanigans.

1) Manually Edit project.vbproj
2) Look for Empty
3) Replace Empty with your project type eg. WindowsForms
4) Save
5) Open your project

Now the tickbox for "Enable Application Framework" is not greyed out and can be clicked, bringing back the Windows XP style of the controls.

The question I still have left (even if not so important now that it is solved) is: why is this happening? Is a bug of Visual Studio? Did not change anything since the install.

Comment: If the vbproj file's `<MyType>` tag had **Empty**, then you created the project using the "Empty Project" template instead of the "Windows Forms App (.Net Framework)" template.  The VB interface has never allowed you to change the project type (via Project Properties page) from or to Empty and as found you need to edit the vbproj file.  The empty project's default output type is WinExe (WinForm application).  The Empty project is the only way to not have the compiler generate the code support for VB's default form instances and it does not support any of the so-called Application Framework.